# Compare data in different types of same index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index moviestore in elasticsearch and have two types under it

say moviestore/actionmovies and moviestore/favouritemovies.

Now , I want to compare what is common data in these two types based on a field like "moviename". Is there any way to find it out. I know NOSQL stores doesn't support joins, however I want to know is there any way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to elaborate a bit more on what you need. What is the common data you want to find? Is it something like same name/ same director etc. If you elaborate on your requirement, there may be alternate ways to solve it also

Comment: yeah prabin added info

Answer (score 0):

The use case is still not clear.

Elastic search does not support pure join like queries but it has the concept of [parent-child relations](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/parent-child.html) which can do join like queries upto a certain extent.

If you are trying to find movies which are both marked as favorite and action or any other tags you can take the approach of parent-child favorite/action/etc as a part of child. You can take the same approach as you would do on a normal RDBMS.

For example:

Movie can be the parent index and you can put the tags like

If you still have to have as two different types then define similar field name in both the type and search on entire index for say moviename. It will give the results from both the types matching the movie name

Comment: The requirement is clear and hope there is a problem in understanding..this answer doesn't provide the solution.Thanks for your time